# Why isn't a protected setter property available from a static method?

Tags: c#, clone, static-methods

I have a static helper clone method of a specific base type which doesn't allow me to set a base property setter.

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T source, DomainKey cloneKey)
    where T : DomainObjectWithKey
{
    T clone = source.Clone(); // binary formatter returns object of type T
    clone.Key = cloneKey; // this does not compile
    return (T)clone;
}

public class DomainObjectWithKey
{
    public DomainKey Key { get; protected set; }
```

The alternative solution was to put the Clone method inside the class itself, which then allowed me to use the protected setter. However, I then have to specify  when calling Clone from my derived objects, which seemed pointless.

Therefore my question is, is it due to encapsulation that I can't call the protected setter method from a static method?

Example of the alternative solution but why do I have to specify the type?

```
category.Clone<Category>(otherCategory.Key); // why do I have to specify <Category> here?

public class Category : DomainObjectWithKey
{
    public long CategoryId { get { return ((IdDomainKey)Key).Id; } }

    public Category(long categoryId)
    {
        Key = new IdDomainKey(categoryId);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

I ended up with having a public property so the Key could be accessed from an instance of a derived class but protected internal for the setter which allowed the static helper method to set the property.

```
public class DomainObjectWithKey
{
    public DomainKey Key { get; protected internal set; }
```

Comment: `protected` means it can only be called from inside the class or derived classes. Extension methods are just static methods to the compiler and do not have `protected` access.

Comment: To what class does Clone<T> belong?

Comment: Clone<T> is a static helper method inside the same DLL as the DomainObjectWithKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected` means that it is visible to the subclasses of `DomainObjectWithKey`. Your `Clone` method appears to be outside of `DomainObjectWithKey`.

Maybe you're looking for `internal`? `internal` allows you access to the member from within the same DLL.

Comment: Not looking for internal as I need subclass of DomainObjectWithKey to set the Key. I've added a section which shows constructor of derived classes.

Comment: @DavidLiddle Then use `protected internal`; that should cover both bases.